# Constraint optimization in Python, what is the difference?

Tags: optimization

I need to optimize with some simple, linear bounds on my parameters.

I can do this in two ways. One, I can use L-BFGS-S and use its simple bound constraints, or I can use optimizers like COBYLA and use their more general constraints which are more advanced.

[image]
[image]

What is the recommended approach here? It seems L-BFGS-B is more suited for the simple bounds I want, while COBYLA is more advanced ... however it could be better precisely because it's more advanced?

Comment: With *comparable solvers*, a general rule would be *use the least general*. In this case though, both solvers are so different, that there is some problem-specific behaviour expected.

Answer (score 0):

The more important questions you should answer first - before thinking about the differences between L-BFGS-B and COBYLA - are: how many variables are you optimizing on? Is you objective function very complicated? Is it convex or highly multi-modal? Is the objective function expensive to evaluate? Are you able to provide the analytical gradient for your objective function? If your objective function is multi-modal, are you happy with a local minimum or are you seeking a global optimum?